# Where to store both passwords for local host and remote server when copying PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

On Windows 7, I try to copy my local database to an already existed empty database on a remote server, so I type the command

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser -d dbname -W
```

I've set `PGPASSWORD` environment variable for my localhost, and I also set password of remote server in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf`, but I still have to add `-W` and type the lengthy password by hand, otherwise I would get a password authentication failure.

What's the relationship between passwords in `PGPASSWORD` and `pgpass.conf`? Can I record the lengthy password for remote server in some place so that I don't need to type by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PGPASSWORD` **overrides** `pgpass.conf`, which is why you're seeing that behavior.

The doc states (emphasis mine):

> The file .pgpass in a user's home
>   directory or the file referenced by PGPASSFILE can contain passwords
>   to be used if the connection requires a password (**and no password
>   has been specified otherwise**).

See the [Password File doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) for more info.

One option to support both would be to have *batch* or *cmd* files wrap the *psql* commands and set the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable accordingly, depending on whether it's the local or remote host.

Another would be to keep multiple password files and set the environment variable `PGPASSFILE` instead. This option is the more secure of the two, since you can set different permissions on the various files, and they aren't directly exposed in a shareable environment variable.

See the [Environment Variable doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-envars.html) for more info.

**Edit:**

And as Richard Huxton mentions in the comment below, both passwords could also be put into the same password file.

Comment: Or of course, just put both passwords into the same password file.